# Create multiple API call parallelly but don't wait to any other response using spring boot project reactor

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor

Zip aggregate given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item, but I want to know, i will call multiple API parallelly but without any dependency i want to exposed response one by one which is available on that time.

So plz help to solve the problem. I have already used Mono.zip, but this has been wait for all responses to arrive.

Comment: `Flux.concat()` could be what you're after to concatenate several `Mono` publishers together? It will then publish multiple elements in the same stream, (publishing an element whenever any of your original `Mono` publishers emits a value.) Your question isn't at all clear though, so I may have got the wrong end of the stick there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `Flux#merge`. The subscription to the publishers is eager(all publishers are subscribed together):

```java
Flux.merge(Mono.just("response1").delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3)),
        Mono.just("response2").delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1)),
        Mono.just("response3").delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
```

The output will be:

```
response2
response3
response1
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it's works for me.

One more question to u,
If i want to continuing the available response to web, that means which response is available i exposed those to front-end via json, then one by one, when all those are completed it will closed. That means open connection to server and client. 
Plz recommend a way to do this. 

Thanks for advance.

Comment: @ArefinIslam Here is a good article on how to stream data using Webflux: https://medium.com/@nithinmallya4/processing-streaming-data-with-spring-webflux-ed0fc68a14de